# decode system.gserviceaccount.com certificate to extract public key

Tags: firebase, certificate, jwt, firebase-authentication, public-key

For jwt token signature verification of firebase generated token the firebase documentations asks to use the following link:

https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com

the above link gives me a Json which is not a plain text, How can I decode and extract public key from it?

any suggestion for a web decoder?

Answer (score 0):

In Python with cryptography module for each certificate you can do:

```
from cryptography.x509 import load_pem_x509_certificate
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
cert = "CERTIFICATEnnnnnnnnnnENDCERT"
key = load_pem_x509_certificate(cert, default_backend())
key.public_key()
```

It's even easier with node.js if that's what you mean by web decoder.

You didn't specify the language nor the output format you want.